# How to return all items where shop review is greater than or equal to input - Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

Item.php

```
class Item extends Model {

     public function shop()
     {
        // belongsTo and not belongsToMany since shops sell used goods, not new goods

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop');
     }
}
```

Shop.php

```
class Shop extend Model {

      public function reviews()
      {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
      }

      public function getRating()
      {
           // I could also do $this->reviews->avg('rating');

           $reviews = $this->reviews->toArray();
           $reviews = array_column($reviews, 'rating');
           $reviews = array_sum($reviews);
           $rating  = round(($reviews / $this->reviews->count()));

           return $rating;
      }
}
```

What I would like to do with the above code is return all the Items where the average shop review is greater than or equal to a given input. For example, if a user selects 3 out of 5 stars then return all Items where the average shop review is 3 or greater. I would like to return the Items, not the Shop. So something like

```
$input = request('input'); // ie: 3
Item::where(*average shop review*, '>=', $input)->get();
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could try with following code:

```
$items = Items::where($this->Shop->reviews->avg('rating'),'>',$input)
                ->get()->toArray();
```

To get the Items data with shop data.

```
$items = Shop::where($this->reviews->avg('rating'),'>',$input)
               ->with('Item')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: `Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::$Shop`

Comment: for which query .. 1st or 2nd